# Autoït using WebDriver, can't open Microsoft Edge with IE mode

Tags: webdriver, microsoft-edge, autoit

I have been using WebDriver with autoit scripts quite a lot to control Firefox and i'm now looking to use it for Edge.

I want to open a WebSite that only work on Microsoft Edge when Internet Explorer mode is enabled, but i can't find a way to make it work.

Here is my code :

```
_WD_Option('Driver', @ScriptDir & '\include\' & (@Compiled ? '' : 'Exe_externe\') & 'msedgedriver.exe')
_WD_Option('DriverParams', '--log trace ')
_WD_Option('Port', 9515)
$sDesiredCapabilities = '{"capabilities": {"alwaysMatch": {"ms:edgeOptions": {"args": ["--ie-mode-force"]}}}}'
_WD_Startup()
```

It results with Microsoft Edge that doesn't open with IE mode enabled and i get an info bar on the top of the brower, saying: "**Turn off remote debugging to open this site in internet explorer mode. Otherwise, it might not work as expected.**".

Is remote bebuging the real issue ? If so, how could i turn it off using Webdriver with autoit script ?

From reading [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/ie-mode?tabs=c-sharp), i might have to use IEDriver instead of msedgedriver in order to manipulate Microsoft Edge with IE mode, but sadly, i can't find any documentation of this with autoit or even any example code (Downloading IEDriverServer.exe + change 'msedgedriver' by 'IEDriverServer' doesn't seems to be enough).

Comment: Remote debugging is not the issue. The point is that you need to use IE driver to automate Edge IE mode. Except from using IE driver, you also need to add IE options to set `AttachToEdgeChrome` to `true` and set `EdgeExecutablePath` to the path of Edge executable file. I'm not familiar with Autoit, you can try if it is feasible to set these IE options using Autoit.

Comment: I managed to make it works using IE driver but for some reason i ignore, Autoit WebDriver UDFs is not working well with IE driver (very slow, often end up in timeout). Is there any way to enable IE mode in Edge using Microsoft Edge WebDriver ? I saw on forums that IE driver had once that 'Turn off remote bebugging' error message before they fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Yu Zhou for the advices, i have managed to run EDGE on IE mode with the following code:

```
_WD_Option('Driver', @ScriptDir & '\include\' & (@Compiled ? '' : 'Exe_externe\') & 'IEDriverServer.exe')
_WD_Option('DriverParams', '--log trace ')
_WD_Option('Port', 5555)
Local $sDesiredCapabilities = '{"capabilities": {"alwaysMatch": { "se:ieOptions" : { "ie.edgepath":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft\\Edge\\Application\\msedge.exe", "ie.edgechromium":true, "ignoreProtectedModeSettings":true }}}}'
$iWDPid = _WD_Startup()
$sWDSession = _WD_CreateSession($sDesiredCapabilities)
```